# How to copy array of struct in C

Tags: c

I have defined struct like

```
typedef struct {
    char *oidkey;
    int showperf;
    char oidrealvalue[BUFSIZE];
    char *oidlimits;
} struct_oidpairs;
```

and I have array of struct

```
 struct_oidpairs b[] ={{.....},....}
```

and I want to copy it to `new struct array a[]`

please help

Comment: What's the point of `typedef struct { ... } struct_oidpairs`?  Why not just `struct oidpairs { ... }`?

Comment: @JeremyP: These are not the same in C.

Comment: Yes they are.  The difference is that in one case, you type a space (or any amount of white space) between the struct and the oidpairs.  In the other case you type an underscore.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
memcpy(dest, src, sizeof(struct) * sizeof(src));
```

Comment: This will not work as expected if oidkey and oidlimits are dynamically allocated strings.

Comment: It makes a shallow copy of the struct, thus it copies the *pointers*, not the contents of the strings.

Comment: Yes as long as `oidkey` and `oidlimits` are constants and not subject to be changed in the copied version of the array AND both the source during the lifetime of the copied array

Comment: How does this memcpy differ from struct copying `a[i]=b[i];` mentioned in the down voted answer (except for the b.size() part, of course)? If the array size is specified properly, wouldn't struct copying work similar to a shallow memcpy?

Answer (score 2):

Your struct contains pointers as data members, this means you will have to roll out your own copy function that will do something sensible with the pointers. `memcpy` only works is all the data related to the struct is stored in the struct.

Answer (score 1):

For real copy of the contents, follow [Sjoerd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182971/sjoerd)'s answer and then:

```
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(src); i++)
{
    if (src[i].oidkey != NULL)
    {
        dest[i].oidkey = malloc(strlen(src[i].oidkey) + 1);
        strcpy(dest[i].oidkey, src[i].oidkey);
    }

    if (src[i].oidlimits != NULL)
    {
        dest[i].oidlimits = malloc(strlen(src[i].oidlimits) + 1);
        strcpy(dest[i].oidlimits, src[i].oidlimits);
    }
}
```

You may consider memcpy if you are interested in speed.

**Update:**

- Following [harper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266487/harper)'s code, I
  updated the code to check NULL
  pointers
- This is a quoted note from
  [gordongekko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/411313/gordongekko):

  > This solution will crash if
  >   `oidkey` or `oidlimits` are `!= NULL` and not
  >   `'\0'`-terminated means not initialized

Comment: You must check for NULL pointers in oidkey and oidlimits to avoid undefined behavior (i.e. page fault). You may consider strdup instead of malloc+strcpy to reduce code lines.


 And you may use strdup instead of malloc+strcpy to save code lines.

Comment: your solution will crash if oidkey/oidlimits are !=NULL and not '\0'-terminated means not initialized.

Comment: @harper: `strdup` is not a standard function. In other words, there's no such function as `strdup` in C.

Answer (score 0):

Makes NOT a deep copy:

```
struct_oidpairs b[] = {...};
size_t len = sizeof b/sizeof*b;
struct_oidpairs *a = malloc(sizeof b);

if( !a ) /* ERROR handling */

memcpy( a, b, sizeof b );
...
free( a );
```

or

```
while( len-- )
  a[len] = b[len];
...
free( a );
```

Answer (score -5):

maybe using :

```
for(int i=0; i<b.size() ;i++) 
//I am not sure if this is the correct name for the size function
{
a[i]=b[i];
}
```