# Invalid Initializer - Array of structs

Tags: c, struct

I am having problems with assigning a value to `cv`. Based on my code below, I am getting `error: invalid initializer` at the line:

```
ChVec cv = r->cv;
```

Would anyone know what the issue might be?

Thanks for your help.

**tuple.c**

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "tuple.h"
#include "reln.h"
#include "hash.h"
#include "chvec.h"
#include "bits.h"

Bits tupleHash(Reln r, Tuple t)
{
    ChVec cv = r->cv;
    ...
    ...
}
```

**chvec.h**

```
#include "defs.h"
#include "reln.h"

#define MAXCHVEC 32

typedef struct {
    Byte att;
    Byte bit;
} ChVecItem;

typedef ChVecItem ChVec[MAXCHVEC];
```

**reln.h**

```
#ifndef RELN_H
#define RELN_H 1

typedef struct RelnRep *Reln;

#include "defs.h"
#include "tuple.h"
#include "chvec.h"
#include "page.h"


struct RelnRep {
    Count  nattrs; // number of attributes
    Count  depth;  // depth of main data file
    Offset sp;     // split pointer
    Count  npages; // number of main data pages
    Count  ntups;  // total number of tuples
    ChVec  cv;     // choice vector
    char   mode;   // open for read/write
    FILE  *info;   // handle on info file
    FILE  *data;   // handle on data file
    FILE  *ovflow; // handle on ovflow file
};
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: - The link will be of help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635053/how-to-copy-array-of-struct-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `ChVec` is an array, you can't initialize an array using another array (just like you can't assign to an array variable).

Instead you need to *copy* the array:

```
ChVec cv;
memcpy(cv, r->cv, sizeof cv);
```

Answer (score 2):

Arrays cannot be assigned the way you are doing.

You must use `memcpy()` to copy contents:

```
ChVec cv;
memcpy(cv, r->cv, sizeof(cv));
```